# Pyspark collect_list and other aggregations with window functions on numeral columns with NaN values

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aggregate-functions

I want to convert a spark dataframe that looks like this below

```
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame([[1, 'name_value', None, 'square', 'polygon'],
                                          [2, 'name_value', 5.5, None, 'polygon']],
                                          columns=['id', 'name', 'area', 'sub_type', 'type']))
```

Fig 1

[image]

to look like Fig 2

[image]

essentially trying to de-duplicate some records be selecting the best available values (mostly just non-null) values for given `name` column

I am trying to use the window operations to get to it but am seeing some weird behavior with float column's `NaN` values

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window


name_window =  Window.partitionBy('name')

(sdf
 .withColumn('min_Id', F.min('id').over(name_window))
 .withColumn('prefered_area', F.first(col('area')).over(name_window.orderBy(col('area').desc_nulls_last())))
 .withColumn('prefered_sub_type', F.first('sub_type').over(name_window.orderBy(col('type').desc_nulls_last())))
 .withColumn('area_list', F.collect_list(col('area')).over(name_window.orderBy(col('area'))))
 .withColumn('sub_type_list', F.collect_list('sub_type').over(name_window.orderBy(col('type'))))
 .withColumn('prefered_type', F.first('type').over(name_window.orderBy(col('type').desc_nulls_last())))
 .toPandas())
```

[image]

Fig 3

See how the `first` and `collect_list` functions work fine for string columns but creates different results for float columns? like for the string column the `prefered_sub_type` column has the desired `square` value but the float column `prefered_area` is `NaN`. I also included the `collect_list` results to show the difference between the float and string columns.

Can someone please take a look and let me know what's the reason for this? and how can I get to my desired dataframe in Fig 2?

Answer (score 0):

I get different results copying and pasting your code, but:

Avoid ordering when using `collect_list` as it messes up results, just use window only:

```
F.collect_list(col('area')).over(name_window))
```

Use `row_number` to check for how exactly the sorting through window occurs to debug:

```
sdf.withColumn('prefered_area_rank', F.row_number().over(name_window.orderBy(col('area').desc_nulls_last())))
```

In order to align with your desired output I had to correct preferred column names you were using, also added the ranks to your sorts. Nulls don't show in lists, I'm using Spark 3.1.2 maybe that's why.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window
import pandas as pd

sdf = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame([[1, 'name_value', None, 'square', 'polygon'],
                                          [2, 'name_value', 5.5, None, 'polygon']],
                                          columns=['id', 'name', 'area', 'sub_type', 'type']))

name_window =  Window.partitionBy('name')

(sdf
 .withColumn('min_Id', F.min('id').over(name_window))
 .withColumn('prefered_area', F.first(col('area')).over(name_window.orderBy(col('area').desc_nulls_last())))
 .withColumn('prefered_area_rank', F.row_number().over(name_window.orderBy(col('area').desc_nulls_last())))
 .withColumn('prefered_sub_type', F.first('sub_type').over(name_window.orderBy(col('sub_type').desc_nulls_last())))
 .withColumn('prefered_sub_type_rank', F.row_number().over(name_window.orderBy(col('sub_type').desc_nulls_last())))
 .withColumn('area_list', F.collect_list(col('area')).over(name_window))
 .withColumn('sub_type_list', F.collect_list('sub_type').over(name_window))
 .withColumn('prefered_type', F.first('type').over(name_window.orderBy(col('type').desc_nulls_last())))
 .toPandas())
```

[image]